# Colorgram: removing Rgb from each element

Tags: python, string, list

I have this list:

[image]

in which I would like to remove all the characters and leave the actual values such that I get the following:

[(157, 155, 164),...,(56, 66, 70)]

I tried

```
s = [x.strip('Rgb(r=') for x in s]
```

but that didn't work, neither did this:

```
s = s.replace("Rgb(r=", "(").replace("g=", "").replace("b=", "")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list of `Rgb` objects, not strings.  You can likely do

```
[(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b) for rgb in s]
```

to get the attributes of those objects.

Edit:  After a little research, it looks like [`Rgb` is a `namedtuple`](https://github.com/obskyr/colorgram.py/blob/master/colorgram/colorgram.py#L17).  That means that they're iterables, so we can just do

```
[tuple(rgb) for rgb in s]
```

though they're already technically tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import colorgram

colors = colorgram.extract("hirst painting.jpg", 10)

rgb_colors = []
for color in colors:
    r = color.rgb.r
    g = color.rgb.g
    b = color.rgb.b
    new_color = (r, g, b)
    rgb_colors.append(new_color)
print(rgb_colors)

#[(253, 251, 248), (254, 250, 252), (232, 251, 242), (198, 12, 32), (250, 237, 17), (39, 76, 189), (38, 217, 68), (238, 227, 5), (229, 159, 46), (27, 40, 157)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came to the same issue. After reading colorgram.py description i have tried to extract 20 colors from an image. I've made it work with this code:

```
import colorgram
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

colors = colorgram.extract("image.jpg", 20) #extracts colors as NamedTuples
pallet_colors = []

for i in range (20):
    rgb = colors[i].rgb #rgb is saved as (Rgb(xxx,xxx,xxx))
    r = rgb.r #r variable is saved as (xxx)
    g = rgb.g #g variable is saved as (xxx)
    b = rgb.b #b variable is saved as (xxx)
    new_color = (r, g, b) #new_color has Tuple form (xxx,xxx,xxx)
    pallet_colors.append(new_color)

print(pallet_colors)
```